# Date formatter date function returns nil when locale is set to German

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert a string to date object using date formatter. Works fine will all locales/languages except for German it returns nil. Below is my code:

```
func convertStringToDate(time: String) {
  let df = DateFormatter()
  df.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
  df.locale = Locale.current // This is de_US for German
  df.timeZone = TimeZone.current
  let date = df.date(from: time) // This is nil in German
}
```

Initially  didn't set locale and timezone in the code, but with locale and timezone, I am still getting nil. Anything I am missing?

Comment: what is your time string?

Comment: If I am converting 24 hours to 12 hours, then time string is 17:00 for 5:00pm. If converting from 12 hours to 24 hours, I set df.dateFormat to "hh:mm a" and time string would be 5:00 PM